# How do I save an interactive application figure in InteractiveDynamics.jl

Tags: julia

In the [documentation](https://juliadynamics.github.io/InteractiveDynamics.jl/dev/agents/#InteractiveDynamics.abm_data_exploration) for abm_data_exploration in the InteractiveDynamics package, it mentions that the user can save the returned figure. Searching the documentation, I have not been able to deduce what the target filetype ought to be or even what function I should use.

Assume that the figure is defined as such

```
figure, adf, mdf = abm_data_exploration(
    model, agent_step!, dummystep, parange;
    ac = groupcolor, am = groupmarker, as = 10,
    adata, alabels
)
```

How might I save this figure (as an interactive application) to disk?

Comment: Are you looking for a picture or an interactive? If you're looking to capture a still image, then @ahnlabb's solution is correct. If you're asking how to display the moving, interactive version of the model, you might specify that.

Comment: @ElliottCollins the latter. A priori I am somewhat skeptical that it is possible, but the documentation seems to imply as much and I try not to assume that julia packages can't do hard things — I've been wrong to do so in the past.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's talk about the most common use-case. The relevant part of the documentation states:

> Calling `abm_data_exploration` returns: `figure, agent_df, model_df`. So you can save the figure, but you can also access the collected data (if any).

The returned `figure` is a [`Figure` from the Makie ecosystem](http://makie.juliaplots.org/stable/figure.html). I believe that what the documentation is hinting at is that after you've finished interacting with the data you can save the final figure as an image or you can process (e.g. plot) the collected data in the dataframes `agent_df` and `model_df`. You can save the figure using [`FileIO.save`](https://juliaio.github.io/FileIO.jl/stable/#Usage) to whatever format your [Makie backend](http://makie.juliaplots.org/stable/backends_and_output.html#Backends-and-Output) supports. To my knowledge, all backends currently support PNG so as an example:

```
save("figure.png", figure)
```

[CairoMakie](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/CairoMakie.jl) supports saving to EPS, PDF, and SVG in addition to PNG.

### Can I save an interactive Makie figure?

The answer could depend on exactly what you want to achieve but it is unlikely that this is something you want to do. When a user interacts with the interface *arbitrary* Julia code can be executed. The person receiving this application needs Julia and in loading the figure the entire state of Julia (modules, globals, functions) needs to be replicated in that session. Within the same session however, you can close the window and then at a latter point redisplay the figure using `display(figure)`.

### Can I create a self-contained relocatable interactive application?

It is possible to compile relocatable apps from Julia code. Not all modules can be included in such relocatable apps, it's not trivial and the resulting binaries are fairly large: [PackageCompiler/Relocatable apps](https://julialang.github.io/PackageCompiler.jl/dev/devdocs/relocatable_part_3/).

Comment: abm_data_exploration() is creating interactive applications. Is there any way to save (or even just display) the application itself, rather than a still image of one?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this @ElliottCollins. I've tried to improve my answer to address this framing of the question.